# How can chrome.storage entries be monitored?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The resources tab in the chrome developer window (for running extension pages) has a section to monitor the current state of localStorage variables. Isn't there a similar section to monitor the variables/objects stored under the newer chrome.storage (both local and sync)?

Comment: Not yet. Feel free to file a feature request at http://new.crbug.com